Getting Error during build: RollupError: expression expected after migrating from vue-cli to vite
I just migrated from vue-cli to vite. Serving locally works fine, but during the build, I got the following error:
x Build failed in 221ms
error during build:
RollupError: Expression expected
    at getRollupError (file:///home/pc/Desktop/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:379:41)
    at ParseError.initialise (file:///home/pc/pc/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:11172:28)
    at convertNode (file:///home/officeubuntu23/pc/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12914:10)
    at convertProgram (file:///home/officeubuntu23/pc/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12234:12)
    at Module.setSource (file:///home/officeubuntu23/pc/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14073:24)
    at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///home/pc/Desktop/proj/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18712:13)

I have tried updating node and npm, reinstalling rollup and doing npm update and npm install.

We encountered that exact same error on my team as well. A team member was using Linux, so he set up some symlinks to a few required resources. The rest of us were using Windows, so the symlinks didn't play nice with Windows/Vite.
Try checking your project for simlinks and see if that is causing the error.
